# PHP, select +1 not working in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So this keeps still returning 1 (the max is 1), when I run the query in phpmyadmin I get 2.

```
function getListingID(){
global $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 $result = $conn->query("SELECT 1, MAX(position)+1 FROM listings");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

return $row[0];
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest aliasing your columns so you can reference them by name so you don't have to worry about the offsets if you change the query.

Comment: Why select 1 and not use it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, or if it matters, but I believe MAX(position)+1 will return null rather than 1 if there are no records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return the index `1` for get the `MAX(position)+1`  (second column index = `1`)

```
return $row[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your query string to be as follows:

```
function getListingID(){
global $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 $result = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(position)+1 FROM listings");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

return $row[0];
}
```